# Encountering problems creating and inserting a table into an MS word doc/template PHP

Tags: php, object, com, ms-word

I'm attempting to create and insert a new table into an MS word document, and I'm having trouble with this, any help would be much appreciated. I'm encountering the following error:

> 'Unable to lookup `InsertTable': Unknown name. '

So obviously my syntax for accessing the function is incorrect but I'm having trouble finding a resource that can succinctly tell me how to do this.

Code sample:

```
//1. Instanciate Word 
        $word1 = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
        echo "Loaded Word, version {$word1->Version}\n";
//2. specify the MS Word template document (with Bookmarks inside) 
        $template_file = "C:\PHP/TEST.docx";
//3. open the template document 
        $word1->Documents->Open($template_file);

// get the bookmark and create a new MS Word Range (to enable text substitution)        
    $bookmarkname2 = "TABLE_Budget";

        if ($word1->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks->Exists($bookmarkname2)) {
            //then create a Table and perform the substitution of bookmark with table 
            $objBookmark1 = $word1->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks($bookmarkname2);
            $table1 = $word1->ActiveDocument->Tables->Add($word1->Selection->Range, 1, 2); //creates table with 2 columns
            //now substitute the bookmark with actual value 
            $objBookmark1->InsertTable = $table1;
        } else {

            echo 'Problem found on ' . $bookmarkname2 . 'insert.';
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what Word PHP library you are using, so it's impossible to give a specific example, however it is highly likely that `InsertTable` is a function and not a parameter

You would use it something like

```
$objBookmark1->InsertTable($tableData);
```

If you are using a 3rd party library such as PHPDocX then you will find documentation on their website (http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/api-documentation)

If you are using the COM object then you can try searching the MSDN ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb726434(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb726434%28v=office.12%29.aspx)), as the object will be documented for the version of Word you are using

(Although if you -are- using the COM directly then you could try something like:

```
//add a table at the bookmark position
$table1 = $word1->ActiveDocument->Tables->Add($objBookmark1->Range, 1, 2);
```

)

Comment: Makes sense, sorry for not adding that detail fully - (only added COM tag) I'm updating my post now, thank you for the feedback thus far, looking through it now!

Comment: I have been able to add a table thanks to your response, only problem is the table has no bordering / styling it's there in the document but basically invisible you need to highlight it to see it's there.

Comment: You can use `$ table1` to add things like borders, such as `$ table1->Borders->InsideLineStyle = <value>`